# I want to construct a pseudo glossary using a table - how do I replicate a hanging indent?

Tags: tables

I want a glossary in my thesis, but have come to the conclusion the `glossaries` package is overkill as I don't want to use much of the functionality. All I want is to be able to manually add a few entries and I can take care of the sort order myself. So I thought I'd have a go at constructing an appropriate table instead. However, it's not as easy as I thought it would be. Here's what I've done so far, adjusting widths and separations as I go along to try to get it to look right:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, fleqn]{report}

\usepackage[showframe, top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, includehead]{geometry}
\geometry{headheight=28pt, headsep=18pt,showframe}


\usepackage{array,booktabs}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\newcommand{\glossrow}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

{
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-5pt}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.05\textwidth}@{} p{0.25\textwidth} @{} p{0.7\textwidth} }

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\glossrow{Here is my new term}} & \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{0.94\textwidth}}{This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term.} \\ \addlinespace

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\glossrow{Here is my new term}} & \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{0.94\textwidth}}{This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term.} \\ \addlinespace

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\glossrow{Here is my new term}} & \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{0.94\textwidth}}{This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term.} \\ \addlinespace

\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

It's a bit of a pain to put in `\multicolumn{2}{l}` on every line. Can someone advise a more automatic way to generate something that looks like the `altlist` format of `glossaries`. Perhaps it's just easier if I go back to using `glossaries` after all!

[image: my glossary]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the description environment to make something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Here is my new term] 

This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term.

\item[Here is my new term] 

This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term.

\item[Here is my new term] 

This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term. This is the definition of my new term.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

If you need the description on a new line you have to use the enumitem-package.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
...  
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
...
```

Comment: Fab your edit just answered my question (which I should also have known myself as I'm already using enumitem)... Much simpler solution, silly me for overcomplicating things! Thanks!